# Reports.ReportManager classified as variable

Tags: apex, reports-api, execute-anonymous

I'm working on a way to collect all the reports that utilize a certain field in my Org, but I'm having a very weird problem.

I've been attempting to run this code in an Anonymous Exe block but keep running up against
`Variable does not exist: ReportManager`

This is the code

```
        List<Report> reports = [SELECT Id FROM Report];
        List<Report> contactReports = new List<Report>();

        
        for (Report reportId : reports) {
            Reports.ReportMetadata metadata = Reports.ReportManager.describeReport(reportId.Id).getReportMetadata();
            List<String> cols = metadata.getDetailColumns();
            for (String column : cols) {
                if (column == 'TITLE') {
                    contactReports.add(reportId);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.debug('Number of Reports: ' + contactReports.size());
```

I'm basing this off of a similar function that I made that works and runs correctly.

```
String reportID = (String)[SELECT Id FROM Report WHERE Id = '00O4x000004PGwTEAW'][0].get('Id');

Reports.ReportMetadata metadata = Reports.ReportManager.describeReport(reportId).getReportMetadata();
List<String> cols = metadata.getDetailColumns();
for (Integer i = 0; i < cols.size(); i++) {
    if (cols[i] == 'TITLE') {
        cols[i] = 'DESCRIPTION';
        break;
    }
}
.
.
.
```

The above code does run without the error, for some reason though, if I copy / paste my non-working code into the above, I start getting the error on the previously running code. I'm entirely flummoxed, I think it might be a scoping issue like with the for loop so I experimented with that to no avail. Any advice is very welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You're shadowing the `Reports` class:

```
List<Report> reports = [SELECT Id FROM Report];
```

Apex is case-insensitive, so this reference

```
Reports.ReportMetadata metadata = Reports.ReportManager.describeReport(reportId.Id).getReportMetadata();
```

resolves to point at the variable `reports` instead of the namespace `Reports`.

Easy fix: change the name of your variable.

Comment: Oh my gosh you're completely correct I feel so foolish, thank you!!